# material-dialogs with edit text and multi choice

Tags: android, material-design, android-dialog

I am using [afollestad/material-dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) to create dialog with edit text and positive and negative buttons. What I want to achieve is adding multi choice input so the user can select an item from a list of items.
my code so far looks like that:

```
 private void buildAlertDialog() {
    final String[] str = {""};
    MaterialDialog builder = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
            .title("Add Item")
            .widgetColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimaryDark))
            .inputMaxLength(30,R.color.material_blue_grey_950)
            .inputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
            .input("add shopping item", "", new MaterialDialog.InputCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onInput(MaterialDialog dialog, CharSequence input) {
                    str[0] = input.toString();
                    //add it to shoppingListItems and save to sharedPreferences
                    shoppingListItems.add(str[0]);
                    saveShoppingItems();
                    isListEmpty();
                }
            }).negativeText("Cancel").show();
}
```

I tried to add neutral button ("add quantity") and when its pressed it displays another dialog, which was Multilist dialog. The problem was that when I press the positive button on this dialog the previous one (the one on the picture) hidden as well. I don't want that. Does anybody as an idea of how can I achieve a dialog with input edit text (for the shopping item) and a multi list choices ? (preferably in one dialog)
What I have now looks like that:
[image]

Comment: What if you seta utoDismiss(false) on the first dialog

Comment: Hmm, I will definetelily try this out later. Thanks! :)

Comment: By the way, to have it all in one dialog I think you need to create and add a custom view

Comment: Yeah, I supposed so, but I don't know how to add this custom dialog window :/ that is why I am sticking with this library

Comment: But you can do it with the library as well, but of course requires to create the logic for the list as well I guess

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev did you find a solution for this? I have the same problem :(

Comment: @Para I think I ended up using a library that allowed me to create such a dialog. I used `com.afollestad.material-dialogs`. Here is a link to my project where I used the library [github-link](https://github.com/georgikoemdzhiev/Quick_Shopping_List/blob/master/app/src/main/java/koemdzhiev/com/quickshoppinglist/adapters/ShoppingListsAdapter.java)